# jQuery Vertical Menu Search filter

Tags: jquery

I have a very big vertical side bar menu and to help out finding ressources in there I need to implement a search that filters each LI items and leaves only those that contains the keywords inputed. The problem I have is that if a keywork is present in the "ul" all other "li" inside does not desapear.

I created a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/naqoek3b/1/

My code looks like this for now

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;
        $("li").each(function (index, value) {
            if (filter == "") {
                $(this).find('ul').css("visibility", "visible");
                $(this).find('li').css("visibility", "visible");
                $(this).find('ul').fadeIn();
            } else if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).find('ul').css("visibility", "hidden");
                $(this).find('li').css("visibility", "hidden");
                $(this).find('ul').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $(this).find('ul').css("visibility", "visible");
                $(this).find('li').css("visibility", "visible");
                $(this).find('ul').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                    <div>
                        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Menu Search...">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/operations/phpl/" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Search<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/idatagrid/pages/custsrch.php">Lookup customer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/SugarCustom/showMap.php">Customer map</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/idatagrid/pages/StyleSearcj.php">Lookup style code</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Links<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="sugarce/index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index">SugarCRM Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/sugarce/index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index">SugarCRM Externalp</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/sh/i6k4bb1vsklqev9/AACKl2mi0J__yJ6WZ9RlLvM7a?dl=0">BIG BILL Marketing Cloud</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/sh/0w5bin00ippiugw/AACqJl4fOz0kO95XilFcTkBna?dl=0">BIG BILL Internal Documents</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/ssSelect.pgm">Sales inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/apgl/php/ar_detail_query.php">AR Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/operations/cgi/wooMenu.pgm" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Woocommerce</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Web Order Pad<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/webOrdEnt.pgm">Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/extranet/cgi/webOrdEnt.pgm">External</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/wopMenu.pgm">Setup Menu</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Select option<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/SelctStyle.pgm?NextProgram=STOKSTATUS">Stock Status Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/SlcOrd4Inq.pgm">Orders Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/OpenOrds.pgm">Open Orders Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CRMSOrds.pgm">Credit Approvals.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/AltWoMenu.pgm">Work Orders System.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/StkTsfMenu.pgm">Warehouse Stock Transfers System.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/UnPckOrds.pgm?Verified=all">Unpicked Orders by CSR.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/UnPckCusts.pgm?Verified=all">Unpicked Orders Customer Summary.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/UpdPickSta.pgm?Inquiry=yes">Picking Slips Inquiry.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/FixShpmtPS.pgm">Transfer shipment to new pick slip #.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/WMGSMenu.pgm">Warehouse Management System</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CoSelect.pgm">Available Stock report</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Reports<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/ConsolOSR.pgm">Consolidated OSR by sales group - on demand.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/ListZeroInv_select.php">List of Zero Price Invoices</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Location Inventory<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whsinvtyInquiry.php">Consolidated OSR by sales group - on demand.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whselocgoodsremainingInquiry.php">List of Zero Price Invoices</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Special Allocation functions<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whsinvtyInquiry.php">Allocate by Style.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whselocgoodsremainingInquiry.php">Over-Allocated Cuts.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whsinvtyInquiry.php">Un-Allocated Order Lines (by Style).</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whselocgoodsremainingInquiry.php">Analysis of Reserved Stock(by Style and/or Customer).</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Check on Goods Available to Sell.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Customer master maintenance<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/apglreport/php/custmast_inquiry.php">Maintain Customer Emails</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/gpsDbgCust.php">Maintain existing customer's GPS coordinates</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/gpsDbgTool.php">Review and approve new customer's GPS coordinates</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/SugarCustom/showMap.php?">Search for customers on a map-External</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="SugarCustom/showMap.php?">Search for customers on a map-Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/scustInq.pgm?type=E">Sugar Customer Inquiry-External</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/scustinq.pgm?type=I">Sugar Customer Inquiry-Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/AsgnCSRCde.pgm">Bulk re-assignment of CSR codes.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Pricing<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/StyPrcLst.pgm">Pricing Inquiry - by Style (2-2-3)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/SpcPrcSum.pgm">Pricing Inquiry - Customer Deals (2-2-4)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CrtFutPrcs.pgm">Style Price Increase - Create future prices</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CpySpcPrc.pgm">Copy Customer Deals pricing to group (2-2-6)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/historyOfSellingPriceChangesInquiry.php">Price List History Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/price_list_request.php">Maintain style groups for price lists (2-2-23)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/badShp2Prc.pgm">Ship-to Custs with bad price codes.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="EDI Custs price code inquiry.">EDI Custs price code inquiry.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> DRP<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DRPSummary.pgm">(DRP) Cuts Required by Product Class.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DRPManFcst.pgm">DRP Maintain Manual Forecasts.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DspManFcst.pgm">DRP Review Manual Forecasts.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DRPStyTrns.pgm">DRP Details by Style.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/ProposedCutList.php">Proposed Cuts List</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/ContrStyls.pgm">Contract Styles missing Inseam &/or Colour in Base.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CvtStyProb.pgm">Contract Styles used as a base for another contract style.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/cutsSummaryInquiry1.php">Production schedule integrated with DRP data</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/images/General%20DRP%20notes.docx">DRP documentation</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CutHdrInq.pgm">Cut Slip inquiry by Cut #.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/OpenPoStyl.pgm">Purchased Finished Goods Delivery Schedule.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/StylesSlct.pgm?NextProgram=STYSTAMNT">Set skus active/inactive/(non)shippable.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If you open up the js finddle and search for "loo" like this:

[image]

The link "Customer map" should not appear because it does not contain the keyword at all.

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        $(`nav li:not(.sidebar-search)`).each(function (index, element) {
        const item = $(element);
          if (item.text().match(new RegExp(filter, 'gi'))) {
            item.fadeIn();
            if (!item.closest('ul').hasClass('nav')){
                item.closest('ul').addClass('in');
            }
          } else {
            item.fadeOut();
            if (!item.closest('ul').hasClass('nav')){
                item.closest('ul').removeClass('in');
            }
          }
        });
    });
});
```

The above should give class "in" to the ul that has the sub li but it's not giving it that class. With out it, the menu is filtered but they remain closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're selecting all the list items, you're also going through the ones which are inside others. So, you just need to verify if they contain the filter string and, if so, make them fade in, if no, make them fade out.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        $(`nav li:not(.sidebar-search)`).each(function (index, element) {
          const item = $(element);
          const parentListIsNested = item.closest('ul').hasClass('nav-second-level');
        
          if (item.text().match(new RegExp(filter, 'gi'))) {
            item.fadeIn();
            if (parentListIsNested){
              item.closest('ul').addClass('in');
            }
          } else {
            item.fadeOut();
            if (parentListIsNested){
              item.closest('ul').removeClass('in');
            }
          }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                    <div>
                        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Menu Search...">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/operations/phpl/" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Search<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/idatagrid/pages/custsrch.php">Lookup customer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/SugarCustom/showMap.php">Customer map</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/idatagrid/pages/StyleSearcj.php">Lookup style code</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Links<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="sugarce/index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index">SugarCRM Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/sugarce/index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index">SugarCRM Externalp</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/sh/i6k4bb1vsklqev9/AACKl2mi0J__yJ6WZ9RlLvM7a?dl=0">BIG BILL Marketing Cloud</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/sh/0w5bin00ippiugw/AACqJl4fOz0kO95XilFcTkBna?dl=0">BIG BILL Internal Documents</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/ssSelect.pgm">Sales inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/apgl/php/ar_detail_query.php">AR Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/operations/cgi/wooMenu.pgm" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Woocommerce</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Web Order Pad<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/webOrdEnt.pgm">Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/extranet/cgi/webOrdEnt.pgm">External</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/wopMenu.pgm">Setup Menu</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Select option<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/SelctStyle.pgm?NextProgram=STOKSTATUS">Stock Status Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/SlcOrd4Inq.pgm">Orders Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/OpenOrds.pgm">Open Orders Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CRMSOrds.pgm">Credit Approvals.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/AltWoMenu.pgm">Work Orders System.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/StkTsfMenu.pgm">Warehouse Stock Transfers System.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/UnPckOrds.pgm?Verified=all">Unpicked Orders by CSR.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/UnPckCusts.pgm?Verified=all">Unpicked Orders Customer Summary.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/UpdPickSta.pgm?Inquiry=yes">Picking Slips Inquiry.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/FixShpmtPS.pgm">Transfer shipment to new pick slip #.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/WMGSMenu.pgm">Warehouse Management System</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CoSelect.pgm">Available Stock report</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Reports<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/ConsolOSR.pgm">Consolidated OSR by sales group - on demand.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/ListZeroInv_select.php">List of Zero Price Invoices</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Location Inventory<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whsinvtyInquiry.php">Consolidated OSR by sales group - on demand.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whselocgoodsremainingInquiry.php">List of Zero Price Invoices</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Special Allocation functions<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whsinvtyInquiry.php">Allocate by Style.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whselocgoodsremainingInquiry.php">Over-Allocated Cuts.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whsinvtyInquiry.php">Un-Allocated Order Lines (by Style).</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/whselocgoodsremainingInquiry.php">Analysis of Reserved Stock(by Style and/or Customer).</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Check on Goods Available to Sell.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Customer master maintenance<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/apglreport/php/custmast_inquiry.php">Maintain Customer Emails</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/gpsDbgCust.php">Maintain existing customer's GPS coordinates</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/gpsDbgTool.php">Review and approve new customer's GPS coordinates</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/SugarCustom/showMap.php?">Search for customers on a map-External</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="SugarCustom/showMap.php?">Search for customers on a map-Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/scustInq.pgm?type=E">Sugar Customer Inquiry-External</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/scustinq.pgm?type=I">Sugar Customer Inquiry-Internal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/AsgnCSRCde.pgm">Bulk re-assignment of CSR codes.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Pricing<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/StyPrcLst.pgm">Pricing Inquiry - by Style (2-2-3)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/SpcPrcSum.pgm">Pricing Inquiry - Customer Deals (2-2-4)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CrtFutPrcs.pgm">Style Price Increase - Create future prices</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CpySpcPrc.pgm">Copy Customer Deals pricing to group (2-2-6)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/historyOfSellingPriceChangesInquiry.php">Price List History Inquiry</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/price_list_request.php">Maintain style groups for price lists (2-2-23)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/badShp2Prc.pgm">Ship-to Custs with bad price codes.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="EDI Custs price code inquiry.">EDI Custs price code inquiry.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> DRP<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DRPSummary.pgm">(DRP) Cuts Required by Product Class.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DRPManFcst.pgm">DRP Maintain Manual Forecasts.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DspManFcst.pgm">DRP Review Manual Forecasts.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/DRPStyTrns.pgm">DRP Details by Style.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/ProposedCutList.php">Proposed Cuts List</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/ContrStyls.pgm">Contract Styles missing Inseam &/or Colour in Base.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CvtStyProb.pgm">Contract Styles used as a base for another contract style.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/php/cutsSummaryInquiry1.php">Production schedule integrated with DRP data</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/images/General%20DRP%20notes.docx">DRP documentation</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/CutHdrInq.pgm">Cut Slip inquiry by Cut #.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/OpenPoStyl.pgm">Purchased Finished Goods Delivery Schedule.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/operations/cgi/StylesSlct.pgm?NextProgram=STYSTAMNT">Set skus active/inactive/(non)shippable.</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: wow it's almost perfect! It's just missing the the add of class "in" to the parrent <ul> if <ul> is not the main nav. I updated my question. I gave it a try but it's not adding the class

Comment: Apparently, it's not working because all your `<ul>` elements, event the nested ones, have the "nav" class. You can check if they have the "nav-second-level" class. I'm going to update my answer.